# Pass a parameter to oneachfeature leaflet

Tags: javascript, typescript, leaflet

I am trying to pass a parameter to bind it with click on a polygon, I have the following:

```
var mapLayer = new L.TopoJSON(jsonMap, {style: style, onEachFeature: onEachFeature.bind(null,null,selectionManager), pane:'borders'}).addTo(this.map); 


 function onEachFeature(feature, layer, selectionManager) {
                    console.log(selectionManager)
                    layer.on({
                        mouseover: highlightFeature,
                        mouseout: resetHighlight,
                        click: dataFilter.bind(null,ID)
                    });
                }

 function dataFilter(selectionManager,e){
                    var layer = e.target;
                    var zoneName = layer.feature.properties.Index;
                    console.log(zoneName)
                    console.log(selectionManager);
                }
```

So my goal here is to read a parameter in dataFilter (which is in this case selectionManager)

Answer (score 11):

As per the Leaflet docs, `onEachFeature` needs to be a function that receives two parameters (`feature` and `layer`). Using [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) in the way you're using it does not do what you want.

Instead, create a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work):

```
function onEachFeatureClosure(dataFilter) {
    return function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        // Your own logic, that uses dataFilter as well as feature and layer
    }
}

L.topoJSON(jsonMap, {
     style: style, 
     onEachFeature: onEachFeatureClosure(selectionManager),
     pane:'borders'
}).addTo(this.map);
```

Note that the return value from `onEachFeatureClosure(selectionManager)` is a function which looks like `function onEachFeature(feat, layer) {...}`.